# Sets and Universes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A universe is a set $\mathcal{U}$ such that:

1) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $y\in x$ implies $y\in\mathcal{U}$

2) $I\in\mathcal{U}$ and $x_i\in\mathcal{U}$ for every $i\in I$ implies $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}x_i\in\mathcal{U}$

3) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $\mathcal{P}(x)\in\mathcal{U}$

4) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $f:x\longrightarrow y$ surjective ($\textbf{and $y$ subset of $\mathcal{U}$}$) implies $y\in\mathcal{U}$

5) $\mathbb{N}\in\mathcal{U}$

where $\mathcal{P}(x)$ denotes the power-set of $x$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of finite ordinals.

Prove that:

A) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $y\subseteq x$ implies $y\in\mathcal{U}$

B) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $y\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $\left\{x,y\right\}\in\mathcal{U}$

C) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $y\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $x\times y\in\mathcal{U}$

D) $x\in\mathcal{U}$ and $y\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $x^y\in\mathcal{U}$.

$\textbf{MY WORK}$:

A) $y\subseteq x\Longrightarrow y\in\mathcal{P}(x)\Longrightarrow y\in\mathcal{U}$.

B) $\left\{1,2\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and $1\longmapsto x,2\longmapsto y$ is surjective, hence $\left\{x,y\right\}$ is in $\mathcal{U}$.

C) $x\times y$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(x\cup y))$

D) $x^y$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(y\times x)$.

Do you think it is correct?

Comment: Note that your statement of axiom (4) is wrong: it should additionally require you to assume that $y\subseteq\mathcal{U}$.  Otherwise, you could deduce that every set is in $\mathcal{U}$, since your argument for B doesn't actually need $x$ and $y$ to be in $\mathcal{U}$, as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try and use axioms (4) and (5) together.  Alternatively, you could use the fact that $\{x,y\}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(x\cup y)$

Comment: I have edited, do you think it is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct!